# Testing for spatial autocorrelation in residuals of OLS regression

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-statistics, regression, autocorrelation

I'm currently working on a dataset that is most likely to have spatial autocorrelation issues.
In particular, I have observations at the region level and I'm trying to run a regression to check whether x has an effect on y. Moreover, I also have control variables regarding the socio-economic characteristics of the regions, w.

I want to check whether, after controlling for w there is still spatial autocorrelation in the residuals of the regression of x on y.
I understand that Moran's I is the standard to check for autocorrelation, but it already implies assuming a particular spatial correlation structure through the weights.

I know two of the standard tests for autocorrelation are the Mantel test and the Durbin-Watson statistic but they both have issues if the data is indeed spatially autocorrelation.

To sum up, I'd like to know if there is a way to test for the spatial autocorrelation of the OLS residuals without assuming any spatial structure between the observations.

Finally, I'm using python for this project so any suggestion as to how to perform such a test with this program would be great.

Comment: Your statement is a bit of a nonsequitur, you cannot have spatial autocorrelation without structure. You could just look for pattern in your residuals. You can just define Wij as binary thus, accounting for adjacency at different lags. But, in the case of weights, they are distance so there nothing imposed in the spatial structure.

Comment: Yes, in the end I ended up using the inverse of the distance matrix (with 0s in the diagonal) as the weight matrix and then used that to compute Moran's I.